# How to increase the home partition of Ubuntu using another partition without reinstalling?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I was on dual boot, then i formatted the other partition to use it with the current ubuntu partition.
[the 2 partitions i want to make as 1 partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10kw7.png)
How to do that safely without losing any data

Comment: You've given no specifics (I have no idea what release etc) so advice will thus be *generic*.  Copy the data to the partition you want to keep; then re-size as per duplicate link.

Comment: Seems you just created `sdb2` since it appears to be empty. If so, just delete this partition and then resize `sdb1`.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- if /dev/sdb2 is empty, **delete** the partition
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sdb1 all the way to the right
- click the Apply icon